# What is the standard for the text alignment for Text Styles in a Design System?

Tags: conventions, design-system, pattern-library

What is the standard for Design System Text Styles alignment?
Figma defaults to align top.

What are the advantages / disadvantages of using Align Top / Align Center / Align Right when designs get coded?

Thank you

Comment: Text alignment isn't necessarily based on the Design System specification... normally it would be linked to the writing style guide and the type of text being displayed. If you are referring to text alignment for UI components, the same applies but needs to be adjusted since it is for a digital writing style guide rather than one that is normally used for physical publishing.

Comment: If this is a two-part question, the first part doesn't make sense. If there were agreed standards for design systems then everyone would use the same one and there would be little point in their existence. You may well ask what the standards exist for the meal of lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Text alignment is not exactly standalone in the design system. Unless you are referring to the context of where text alignment is applied or being displayed. For instance, in title bars, sub title bars, paragraph text, captions.